# How to set a value of a variable in queryset using(alias) in apiview class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm able to fetch the values from the table with in the database named '11' by using the below line of code.

```
queryset = JobSeekers.objects.using("11").all()
```

Now i would like to to pass the variable instead of static alias name. (here i'm using a global variable 'IdentificationNumber' which is getting set in AuthBackends.py)

```
class GetCanidatesList(generics.ListAPIView):
    authorizedID = str(AuthBackends.IdentificationNumber)
    queryset = JobSeekers.objects.using(authorizedID).all()
    serializer_class = CandidatesSerializer
    name = 'candidates-list'
```

I'm new to Django. Is that possible? Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, why would that not be possible? Django does not even know the expression that generated the string. As long as `authorizedID` is a string, there is no problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thanks for the comment. Here i'm setting Identification number in another .py file, and when i run this code it connecting to default table instead of table '11'. Did i made any mistake?

Comment: As long as IdentificationNumber is not itself generated by a database query, though.

Comment: Please use `JobSeeker` instead of `JobSeekers` (singular, not plural) for your model classes. For the views you should try to use nouns too, ideally the model name plus the view type, for example something like `CandidateList`, but not `GetCandidatesList`. Names starting with verb should be used for methods. I just wanted to add my two cents, as I regard naming things for the most important programmer's skill.